# Confidence intervals for beta regression

Tags: beta-regression

I have used the betareg package in R to fit a regression. My question is: how do I calculate confidence intervals for betaregression in R?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "confidence interval" in this context? Do you want a CI for some parameter? Do you want a conficence *band* for the model? Do you want *prediction* intervals for some y-hat values? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

The beta likelihood is not a regular exponential family, so constructing interval estimates for such two parameter families is not easily done. I think Zeileis was wise not to implement any de-facto methods for `confint`. The cited article Ospina suggests that bootstrap interval estimates perform best. The package `boot` has some methods, but bootstrapping is also easily done "by-hand" in R.

Comment: In essence yes. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230501/variance-vs-standard-deviation-in-beta-regression/230681#230681 for a few more comments.

Comment: One more comment about `confint`: This is not for confidence intervals of _fitted values_ but for confidence intervals of _coefficient estimates_. The default method works if there is a `coef` and a `vcov` methods (which is the case for `betareg`) and returns Wald confidence intervals based on the asymptotic normal distribution of the maximum likelihood parameter estimates.

Comment: @AchimZeileis A celebrity sighting on my post! Indeed I assumed the OP was asking about CIs for the parameter estimates. Help me understand something: Wald based CIs using `coef` and `vcov` methods are not necessarily asymptotically correct for MLEs unless the likelihood is a regular exponential family. Take linear mixed models from the `lme4` package, they don't recommend creating inference from the information matrix and coefficients from the fixed effects. They use profile/bootstrap CI methods, is this to improve efficiency or reduce bias?

Comment: (Not sure about the celebrity thing...anyways:) Of course, the maximum likelihood estimates and their associated confidence intervals are biased in finite samples. As Kosmidis & Firth (2010, EJS) showed, the bias in beta regressions can become quite large, especially for the precision estimates. They have suggested a generic approach for reducing the bias and we have implemented this in `betareg(..., method = "BR")`.